# compare date tag value

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a script that sorts information out and then it has to take a decision based on a match's date, the problem is that I am not sure how to tell the script which is the newest game, here is the XML file:

```
<Games>
  <Game>
    <Date>Sunday, June 29</Date>
    <Time>8:05 PM</Time>
    <Away>Boston</Away>
    <ScoreAway>8</ScoreAway>
    <Home>NY Yankees</Home>
    <ScoreHome>5</ScoreHome>
    <Status>Final</Status>
    <Result>Won</Result>
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Date>Monday, June 30</Date>
    <Time>7:10 PM</Time>
    <Away>Chicago Cubs</Away>
    <ScoreAway>2</ScoreAway>
    <Home>Boston</Home>
    <ScoreHome>0</ScoreHome>
    <Status>Final</Status>
    <Result>Lost</Result>
  </Game>
</Games>
```

Now, I know how to retrieve the information from the Nodes, but I don't know how to compare them or how to tell the script what is newer than the other.

Comment: How can you tell the order? There is no year in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you could use the [`CDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [`DateValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we249285%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to convert your date and time strings to date/time values.

```vbs
WScript.Echo CDate(node.text)
```

However, while this will work for the values of the `<Time>` nodes, the `<Date>` nodes use a custom format which the function doesn't recognize. The best way would be to change the format used in those nodes to a recognized format, e.g.:

- `Jun 29, 2014`
- `2014-06-29`
- `6/29/2014`

If that's not possible, you need to parse the string yourself, i.e. [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) the string and then build a date value from its parts:

```vbs
Set monthNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To 12
  monthNames.Add MonthName(i), i
Next

d = Split(node.text)
WScript.Echo DateSerial(Year(Date), monthNames(d(1)), CInt(d(2)))
```

Note that I'm assuming here that you'll always be looking at the current year whenever you run the script. If that's not the case you need to replace `Year(Date)` with something more appropriate.

Comment: Good solution, but instead of using `Year(Date)`, which will give different results for the same input in the future, the year should be hardcoded to the (hopefully) knonw value.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner OTOH that would mean he'd have to modify the script if he wants to run it next year on new data. I added a note.

Comment: One more thing, I ran the code and right now it returns 12/29/2013 and 12/30/2013, what do you think this could be? @Ansgar